# Use of the 'command' built-in in Bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, posix

What is the use of the 'command' bash shell built in?  [This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) page says that it suppresses the shell function lookup, but I am not sure what it means. Can you explain or give an example?

Comment: Please make the link to point to the right location.

Comment: Note that the 'command' can also be used to suppress shell builtin command lookup. For example, `time` executes a shell builtin command, whereas `command time` or `\time` executes an executable `/bin/date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe:

```
$ date() { echo "This is not the date"; }
$ date
This is not the date
$ command date
Tue Aug  2 23:54:37 PDT 2016
```

Comment: Cool ++ The best example ever  ;) ++

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a simple example of a function.  We want to make sure that `cp` always uses the `-i` option.  We could do that using an alias, but aliases are simple and you can't build much intelligence into them.  Functions are much more powerful.

We might try this (remember, this is just a simple example):

```
cp() {
    cp -i "$@"
}

cp gash.txt gash2.txt
```

That gives us infinite recursion!  It just keeps calling itself.  We could use `/bin/cp` in this case, but this is what `command` is for:

```
cp() {
    command cp -i "$@"
}

cp gash.txt gash2.txt
```

That works, because now it ignores the `cp` function.